Is there a way to count how many infinite cycles there are?
Note: When I wrote $ x = \overline{x_nx_{n-1} ... x_2x_1}$
I meant the representation in base 10 of the number x , that is $=10^{-1}x_+10^{−2}x_{−1}+...+ 10x_2+x_1$ and note that $x_1,x_2,...,x_$ are non-zero digits. When I wrote $i = \overline{1,k}$ I meant that  is an integer which can take values from $1$ to $$.
Problem : We consider a natural number that does not contain any zero digit. We call the 0-transformation of the number $ x = \overline {x_nx_{n-1}...x_2x_1}$ , the next number $ y=\overline {y_ny_{n-1}...y_2y_1} $, formed like this : $y_k = (\sum_{i=1}^k x_k) \% 10 $ for $k = \overline{1,n}$  and we write $x \longrightarrow y $(if a $y_k$ is $0$ then we remove it ; for example $ 325 \longrightarrow 75 $ and $ 82 \longrightarrow 2 $  )  . I am trying to find how many numbers with digits $\neq 0$ under $10 000$ have a chain of finite 0-transformations ( a chain of 0-transformations is finite if after a number of 0-transformations the initial number becomes a digit where the chain stops). For example $$ 29781 \longrightarrow 75691 \longrightarrow 8161 \longrightarrow 6871 \longrightarrow2681 \longrightarrow7591 \longrightarrow 251 \longrightarrow 861 \longrightarrow 571 \longrightarrow381 \longrightarrow 291 \longrightarrow 21 \longrightarrow 31 \longrightarrow41 \longrightarrow51 \longrightarrow 61 \longrightarrow71 \longrightarrow 81 \longrightarrow 91 \longrightarrow1  $$
has a finite number of 0-transformations but the number $225$ doesn't.(we do not take into account cycles of length one, for example if the number reaches the form of a digit we stop there and we say that it had a finite number of 0-transformations)
My approach : I manage to find all the cycles for 2 digits numbers . Let's say that a number $x_1$ has a k-cycle if $ \overline{a_1b} \longrightarrow \overline{a_2b} \longrightarrow ... \longrightarrow \overline{a_kb} \longrightarrow \overline{a_1b} $ condition equivalent to the system $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a_1+b=a_2 + 10m_1 \\ 
a_2+b=a_3 + 10m_2\\ 
... \\
a_k+b=a_1 + 10m_k
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
where $m_i = \{ 0 , 1 \}$ for $i = \overline{1,k}$.
If we sum , we get that $kb = 10x$ where $x = \overline{1,k-1}$.I will prove that for 2 digit numbers we have only cycles of length 2 or 5. First $ k < 10 $ . If $ b =5 $ we get that for every $a_1 \ne 5$ we get a cycle with the length of 2 . If we make $k = 2$ we need to have $b_1 = 5$ so we have a 2-cycle $\iff$ the number is $\overline{a5}$ where $a = \overline{1,9} , a \ne 5$ . If $ k \ge 6 \implies b = 5 $ but the only cycles with b = 5 are of length 2 so we get a contradiction.For a $3$ or $4$ cycle it's easy to also see that it doesn't work(if $k=3$ we can't have $b=10$ and if $k=4 \implies b = 5 \implies k = 2$ false ) . So we only have the case when $k=5$ left where after some calculations with have the following patterns :
$$12 \longrightarrow 32 \longrightarrow 52 \longrightarrow 72 \longrightarrow 92$$ a jump of 1 : $ 1 \ \curvearrowright 3 \curvearrowright 5 \curvearrowright 7 \curvearrowright 9 $
$$14 \longrightarrow 54 \longrightarrow 94 \longrightarrow 34 \longrightarrow 74$$ a jump of 2 : $ 1 \ \curvearrowright 5 \curvearrowright 9 \curvearrowright 3 \curvearrowright 7 $
$$16 \longrightarrow 76 \longrightarrow 36 \longrightarrow 96 \longrightarrow 56$$
a jump of 3 : $ 1 \ \curvearrowright 7 \curvearrowright 3 \curvearrowright 9 \curvearrowright 5 $
$$18 \longrightarrow 98 \longrightarrow 78 \longrightarrow 58 \longrightarrow 38$$ a jump of 4 : $ 1 \ \curvearrowright 9 \curvearrowright 7 \curvearrowright 5 \curvearrowright 3 $
Now when I moved to the 3 digits , I tried to show there are no cycles where we only have 3 digits numbers , so after a number of 0-transformations we will end of on these previous 2 digits cycles . I ran out of ideas further. It is clear that a strong idea is needed to find a method to count these numbers and how they transition.What do you think ? I am open to any suggestion, comment or solution. Thank you !

Your notation needs explanation (you use a line over an expression in two ways I’m not familiar with), but if I understood you, if you look at the initial definition of a 0-transformation, a single digit transforms to itself in a loop of length $1$. Saying the chain stops at a single digit seems arbitrary. But if you ask how many numbers have a chain that eventually reaches a single digit, you get the same answer whether you stop then or keep cycling on the single digit.

When I wrote $x= \overline{a_na_{n-1}...a_1}$ I meant the representation in base 10 of the number x , that is $x = 10^{n-1}a_n + 10^{n-2}a_{n-1} + ... + a_1$ and note that $a_1 , a_2 , ... , a_n $ are non-zero digits. When I wrote $ i = \overline{1,k}$ and  the others I meant that $i$ is an integer which can take values from $1$ to $k$ . If after a finite number of 0-transformations we reach a single digit we stop , if we got stuck in a loop for example $25 - 75$ we say that the chain has an infinite number of 0-transformations because it can't reach a single digit.I hope everything is clearer

All of those responses are things that should be edited into the question to make it more self-contained.
